# Dictionary with delegate as value

Tags: c#, .net

I have following class

```
public class CVisitor : IVisitor
    {
        public int Visit(Heartbeat element)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Heartbeat"); 
            return 1;
        }
        public int Visit(Information element)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Information"); 
             return 1;
        }

    }
```

I want to have a Dictionary with mappings, that every argument type will be mapped to it's implementation function:Heartbeat will be mapped to `public int Visit(Heartbeat element)`

I thought to do something like following:

```
    _messageMapper = new Dictionary<Type, "what should be here ?" >();
    _messageMapper.Add(typeof(Heartbeat), "and how I put it here?" );
```

what should I put instead "what should be here ?" and "and how I put it here?"

Thanks

Comment: How does your methods look (i.e. are they similar in definition?)

Comment: maybe, you could create your methods as Delegates, and your TValue in your Dictionary will be System.Delegate.. have you tried that ?

Comment: @Yet Another Geek, the Visitor function have completely different implementation , they are DTO mappers

Comment: What will the signatures of the delegate values of your dictionary be? I'm not sure this approach will be useful. But if the methods will have many different signatures, like different number of parameters, remember that `System.Delegate` is a base type of `Func<>`, `Func<,>`, `Func<,,>` and all other (BCL or user-defined) delegate types. So `new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>()` is a possibility. But it does not ensure that the value delegate is related in any way to the dictionary key (the `Type`). And like I said, I'm not sure this approach is useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, int>>();

var cVisitor = new CVisitor();
_messageMapper.Add(typeof(Heartbeat), 
   new Func<object, int>(heartbeat => cVisitor.Visit((Heartbeat)heartbeat)) 
);
```

Comment: why you are using Action ? I have a return value there

Comment: if cVisitor is instance of CVisitor  how I registering it with new Func<object, int>(heartbeat => (cVisitor.Visit(heartbeat))

Comment: @NightWalker check current variant

Answer (score 3):

Do you know [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) and [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) objects? Seems like what you are looking for.

```
var d = new Dictionary<Type, Action>();
d.Add(typeof(HeartBeat), ()=>Trace.WriteLine("todum todum"));
```

PS: thx YAG

Comment: If you want to do it this way, then it should be `Action` and not `Action<string>` as no string input is given

Answer (score 1):

Your best call here is to use Reflection.
1. Get all methods of Visitor Class (Or all methods  called "Visit" ?) with typeof(Visitor).GetMethods().
2. GetMethods returns an IEnumerable of MethodInfo. GetParameters will give you the parameters for each Method.
3. So now you can build your Dictionnary of (Type, MethodInfo)
4. use Invoke to call the Method.

Rq : An advantage of using reflection is that the Dictionnary will still be up to date if you add a new method. No risk of forgetting to add a method.

Comment: I came here looking for information since I am essentially doing the same thing. Though I only have a few functions with different signatures, I wanted them all in one dictionary. I was already using reflection for the same reason you outlined...but I didn't even think of storing the method info! Easy solution without needing to create delegates.