# Add Generic Delegates as Dictionary value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want create a Dictionary with Key as string and Value as Delegates like

```
private Dictionary<string, Delegate> Mapping = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
```

I need a generic delegate to return different values based on delegate method.

```
public delegate T MyDelegate(string value);
```

my delegate event should return different values like int ,string, boolean...etc

Now i would like to add it to dictionary Mapping like

```
Mapping.Add("Test",Add mydelegate here)
```

Can any one help me how to add delegate to dictionary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503887/dictionary-with-delegate-as-value

Comment: MyDelegate should be able to return different types of values like string ,int,boolean....etc?

Comment: How are you going to use the delegates when the return type can be a variety of types?

Comment: @O.R. Mapper Suppose i have 3 methods with signature as string and return type as int,string,bool. I have created a Dictionary and added these 3 methods  to Dictionary. Later i will execute these methods through dictionay. Correct me if i am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your delegate declaration or functions must have a concrete return type (which can be assigned through generics). Once this return type is fixed, values inserted in your dictionary must have the same return type. Thus, you can not do what you are asking.

However, you could use `object` as the return type of the delegate and have each function return whatever type they will (eg. `int`, `string`, `boolean`, ...). The downside is that the code consuming that return type will most likely have to check the return type and perform the necessary cast (using `is` or `as` keywords).